# Touches Ended Will Not Call A Method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsdictionary

I have touches ended implemented for a CCLayer in cocos2D.
When a touch is received, it calls a method.. however, calling the method seems to always result in the app crashing due to "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
In the method that I call, I try to read from a NSMutableDictionary
Here's my code:

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];
    int current = 1;
    int i = 1;
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        CCNode *sprite = [layer2 getChildByTag:i];
        CGPoint worldCoord = [layer2 convertToWorldSpace:sprite.position];
        CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(worldCoord.x-sprite.boundingBox.size.width, worldCoord.y-sprite.boundingBox.size.height/2, sprite.boundingBox.size.width, sprite.boundingBox.size.height);
        //CCLOG(@"Sprite%i:%f,%f at %f,%f",i,bounds.size.width,bounds.size.height,bounds.origin.x,bounds.origin.y);
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, touchPoint)) {
            CCLOG(@"touched sprite:%i",i);
            current = i;
            [self checkSpriteTouch:current]; //error occurs when this method is called

            break;
        }
    }
}
-(void)registerWithTouchDispatcher{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:NO];
}


-(void)checkSpriteTouch:(int)i{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [storeDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Char%i",1]]; //when using debugging, app crashes here at this line
    NSNumber *boughtValue = [dict objectForKey:@"Bought"];
}
```

Why does my application crash? All other methods which I implement in my other touchEnded methods work perfectly fine... 
Thank you in advance! Any help is GREATLY appreciated ^_^

Comment: Voting to close as Too Localized; you don't include enough information in your question to have lead to the conclusion that you posted as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why accessing that method would cause my app to crash.
The answer was in accessing the Dictionary.
I had not retained it properly, thus causing the bad access warnings.
To fix it, in the header file, I used:
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *storeDict;
and now, everything works fine! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

storeDict is empty or nil?

Also the i think that should be i instead of 1

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [storeDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Char%i",i]];
```

Comment: if storeDict was empty or nil it wouldn't crash. storeDict must be garbage, perhaps it was never retained upon creation?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it's because of either of this. My store dict is not empty for sure because I CCLogged it and got positive results. Is it because I am trying to get an object from my store dict?

Comment: How did you populate/create the store dict?

Answer (score 0):

So `(int)i` did nothing in `checkSpriteTouch`, I have no idea why you have to put i in your method.

Besides, you should check the implementation of `storeDict`, "i"'s value when it crashed. Maybe you have to put codes here so we can check it.